# Fechar Sessao PHP

Tags: php, session

Olá!

No meu arquivo php tenho o código

> **page.php**

```
session_start();
$valor = isset($_SESSION['usuario']) ? 'S' : 'N';
if($valor == 'N'){
    header('location: .');
}
echo "Sesssao: ".$valor;
```

para sair, em outro arquivo eu faço ao clicar no link para sair que chama a esta função

```
function sair(){
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = null;
    header('location: .');
    session_commit();
}
```

Mas quanto eu acesso a direto pagina que verifica a sessão, sem passar pelo login ele disse que sempre existe sessão
será se é por tem a palavra session_start();

Comment: Onde fica essa função `sair()`? Ela está no mesmo arquivo que o `page.php` ?

Comment: em outra pagina eu chamo a função

Comment: A instrução `session_start()` deve estar em todas as páginas que manipulam sessão. A questão é que quando você roda o `session_destroy`, ele não entende qual sessão deve excluir. Adiciona a instrução `session_start()` antes de destruir. O melhor é colocar a `session_start()` no index.php ou no primeiro script que será sempre executado.

Comment: No index já tem a session_start

Comment: Funcionou! Era isso mesmo! Coloquei a `session_start()` antes do `session_destroy()`